# Doubt about rights in a project

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property

I worked on a project financed by a state agency in my country, Peru.
The legal representative of the project before the organization called Innovate Peru, died recently, the last year and a half due to mismanagement of funds, I worked part-time ad honorem only I as the project developer.

I contacted the agency, and they told me to contact the executing company, but this company did not show any interest in the project.

Currently I have 100% of the project(source code) in my hands, and I plan to modify it a bit for a pilot and present it to investors or seed capitals.

My question is, is this legal? ,What could I do? . The person had given me rights for working time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First question is, did you get paid for your work? In that case whoever paid you probably has some rights. They would likely have the right to *use* the code that you have written, but not more.

Second question is, do you own the copyright? That would require knowledge of Peruvian copyright law; in western countries the company usually owns the copyright if it was a "work for hire" *and* you got paid. Otherwise there should be a contract that says what the company would receive and when.

If the executor of a bankrupt company isn't interested in your work, then no matter what the legal situation is, you might never hear of them again, and your involvement with "Innovate Peru" might be completely forgotten.

Comment: Hello friend, they paid me the first 7 months, then for about a year and a half I was working without payment, 80% of the code was written by me, and the other 20% by other developers who were in the project.

Regarding intellectual property, I have a contract where they assign me part of the participation, I do not know if that counts as part of the intellectual property.

I wanted to have some notion because I really do not have knowledge regarding these types of cases, and thus avoid upsets later.

Comment: In the remote case that they ever ask me for the code, should I give them the code up to the date they paid me? (the first 7 months), and from the job that I did not receive payment they no longer have the right.

Comment: In that case, you don't have the copyright for 20% of the code. And you may not have the copyright for code you have written in the first seven months. If they ask for the code, I would not volunteer anything, but ask for the complete payment to hand them the complete code. I assume that nobody is much interested for the 7 months of code, so that gives you a chance at least to negotiate and get _some_ money.